# Creating ControlTemplate programmatically

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I have a simple set up like this.

1. ContentControl in XAML
2. Add AdornerY to the adorner layer in the code-behind to the ContentControl
3. AdornerY's template is set to my custom ControlTemplate AdornerTemplateY

I'm quite sure  1 and 2 shall not give any problems so I'm posting the code here for the 3.

Visual Studio Express is not very friendly with errors and it merely says:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in PresentationFramework.dll

What's wrong with the code? Thanks a bunch.

```
class AdornerTemplateY : ControlTemplate
{
    FrameworkElementFactory Chrome;

    public AdornerTemplateY(ContentControl designerItem)
        : base(typeof(AdornerY))
    {
        Chrome = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Rectangle));
        Chrome.SetValue(Rectangle.NameProperty, "INTERNAL_CHROME");
        Chrome.SetValue(Rectangle.FillProperty, Brushes.PowderBlue);
        Chrome.SetValue(Rectangle.StrokeProperty, Brushes.Black);
        Chrome.SetValue(Rectangle.DataContextProperty, designerItem);
        Chrome.SetValue(Rectangle.IsHitTestVisibleProperty, true);
        this.VisualTree = this.Chrome;
        this.Triggers.Add(CreateTrigger());
    }

    private Trigger CreateTrigger()
    {
        Trigger TriggerFocus = new Trigger
        {
            Property = AdornerY.IsMouseOverProperty,
            Value = true,
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter
                {
                    Property = AdornerY.VisibilityProperty,
                    Value = Visibility.Collapsed
                },
            }
        };
        return TriggerFocus;
    }
}
```